# why redis query is returning empty docs?

Tags: json, python-3.x, redis

I have placed a JSON in redis server, and I am trying to search using query but I am wondered why I am getting empty docs.

> Result{0 total, docs: []}

I used Redis 4.1.1

Below is input Json.

```
{'data': {'code_description': ['Official: 00100 Anesthesia for procedures on salivary glands, including biopsy', 'Consumer Friendly Full: Anesthesia services for a procedure on the inside of the mouth. Procedures can include removing a sample of tissue for testing (biopsy), tumor removal and saliva gland surgery.', 'Consumer Friendly Short: Anesthesia for mouth procedure'], 'color_codes': 'ASC Payment Indicator - IM Not allowable on a Medicare ASC claim. These codes represent physician and nonphysician practitioner professional services or services billable only by another type of entity. Physician and nonphysician practitioner professional services must be billed on a separate claim from the ASC services.', 'codingtip': 'Coding Tip For anesthesia performed during intraoral procedures other than those of the salivary glands, see codes 00170–00176.  Documentation Tip No Documentation Tip available for this code. Reimbursement Tip No Reimbursement Tip available for this code.', 'lay_description': ' ', 'code_specific_reference_information': 'AHA Coding Clinic References AMA CPT® Knowledge Base AMA CPT® Section Guidelines Annotations Optum Specialty Articles Total CPT®', 'code_range_notes': 'INCLUDES:    EXCLUDES:  ', 'code_history': 'Change Effective Date:01/01/2000\nChange Summary:Officially recognized, Full, medium and short description, Changed\nChange Effective Date:01/01/1990\nChange Summary:Officially recognized, Other, New', 'emca_doc_id': '', 'audr_doc_id': '506681', 'modifiers': {'physician': ['22', '23', '51', '52', '52', '53', '58', '58', '59', '59', '76', '76', '77', '77', '78', '78', '79', '79', '99', 'AA', 'AA', 'AD', 'AD', 'AI', 'AQ', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AR', 'CC', 'CR', 'ET', 'EY', 'G8', 'G8', 'G9', 'G9', 'GA', 'GC', 'GJ', 'GK', 'GR', 'GU', 'GY', 'GZ', 'KX', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4'], 'facility_opps': ['CC', 'CR', 'ER', 'ET', 'EY', 'GA', 'GJ', 'GK', 'GR', 'GU', 'GY', 'GZ', 'KX', 'PD', 'PO', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'QJ'], 'mpfs_medicare': ['51', '52', '58', '59', '76', '77', '78', '79', 'AA', 'AD', 'AQ', 'AR', 'G8', 'G9', 'QK', 'QS', 'QX', 'QY', 'QZ', 'XE', 'XP', 'XS', 'XU'], 'dme_supply': [], 'ambulance': [], 'asc_modifier': ['GA', 'GY', 'GZ']}}}
```

I tried below code snippet.

```
import json
import logging
import time

import redis
from redis.commands.json.path import Path
from redis.commands.search.field import TextField
from redis.commands.search.indexDefinition import IndexDefinition, IndexType
from redis.commands.search.query import Query

search_pattern = "intraoral"

r = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(
    "redis://redis-xxxxx.cxxx.ap-south-x-x.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com",
    port=13231,
    db=0,
    decode_responses=True,
    password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
)
print(r)

# Total records - 1000
for i in range(10):
    x = json.dumps(
        json.load(open("C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/00100.json"))
    )
    y = x.lstrip("[")
    z = y.rstrip("]")
    pure_json = json.loads(z)
    print("pure_json: ",pure_json)
    r.json().set("data:" + str(i), Path.rootPath(), pure_json)

schema = (
    TextField("$.data.color_codes", as_name="color_codes"),
    TextField("$.data.modifiers", as_name="modifiers"),
    TextField("$.data.modifiers", as_name="codingtip"),
)
r.ft().create_index(schema, definition=IndexDefinition(prefix=["data:"], index_type=IndexType.JSON))
q1 = Query(search_pattern).return_field(
    "$.data.codingtip",
    as_field="codingtip",
)
start = time.time()
print("****", r.ft().search(q1))
print("****", r.ft().search(q1).total)
print("****", r.ft().search(q1).docs)
end = time.time()
print("Fetched in %.2f seconds" % (end - start))
```